# RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than 49?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm somewhat new to regular expressions and am writing validation for a quantity field where regular expressions **need** to be used.

How can I match all numbers greater than or equal to 50?

I tried

```
[5-9][0-9]+
```

but that only matches 50-99. Is there a simple way to match all possible numbers greater than 49? (only integers are used)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't use a regex to extract the numeric portion, then from there convert it and test it as a number? Seems like it would be much simpler.

Comment: It needs to use regex in order to be compliant with our system. It's too long and convoluted of a story for this comment block. Needless to say if there was another way, I would use it. @ridgerunner only integers are used.

Comment: we have a use case where we want to block deep paging requests (e.g. page > 150) using AWS WAF, which has regex matching but no numerical matching

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The fact that the first digit has to be in the range `5-9` only applies in case of two digits. So, check for that in the case of 2 digits, and allow any more digits directly:

```
^([5-9]\d|\d{3,})$
```

This regexp has beginning/ending anchors to make sure you're checking all digits, and the string actually represents a number. The `|` means "or", so either `[5-9]\d` or any number with 3 or more digits. `\d` is simply a shortcut for `[0-9]`.

**Edit:** To disallow numbers like `001`:

```
^([5-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,})$
```

This forces the first digit to be not a zero in the case of 3 or more digits.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well. I feel like I really learned something. +1

Comment: @pimvdb: Your use of `^` and `$` would imply that the entire string is numeric. This begs the question, why is a regex needed?

Comment: One minor issue is that it still matches '001' and other numbers with two leading zeroes, but I think this is probably ok.

Comment: @ЖΞЖ: True, but it is explicitly stated in the question so there probably is some reason or another. @ Maxx: You'd have to disallow `0`s at the beginning. Please see my edit.

Comment: @pimvdb Fair enough, and I didn't want it to sound like I was attacking your answer. I'm just not convinced that the constraint placed on the solution is valid, especially since no sample input was provided.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thanks! @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ - Yea, due to the nature of our system, regex has to be used.

Comment: For MySQL: `^([5-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})$`

Comment: inspiring, but number like 055 will not match, which is wrong. @Tiago's answer is the correct one.

Comment: I had to reverse the test so it matches unlimited first or else the counting-up-from pattern always caught to first 2 digits https://regex101.com/r/0eH75W/2

Answer (score 30):

I know there is already a good answer posted, but it won't allow leading zeros. And I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so...
Here's my solution allowing leading zeros:

First I match the numbers 50 through 99 (with possible leading zeros):

```
0*[5-9]\d
```

Then match numbers of 100 and above (also with leading zeros):

```
0*[1-9]\d{2,}
```

Add them together with an "or" and wrap it up to match the whole sentence:

```
^0*([1-9]\d{2,}|[5-9]\d)$
```

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

Try a conditional group matching `50-99` or any string of three or more digits:

```javascript
var r = /^(?:[5-9]\d|\d{3,})$/
```

Answer (score 3):

[Next matches](https://regex101.com/r/vA3hW3/5) all greater or equal to `11100`:

```
^([1-9][1-9][1-9]\d{2}\d*|[1-9][2-9]\d{3}\d*|[2-9]\d{4}\d*|\d{6}\d*)$
```

[For greater or equal](https://regex101.com/r/vA3hW3/4) `50`:

```
^([5-9]\d{1}\d*|\d{3}\d*)$
```

See pattern and modify to any number. 
Also it would be great to find some recursive forward/backward operators for large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
[5-9]\d+|\d{3,}
```

Comment: This is close, but numbers like '444' don't match.

Comment: @Maxx, it does match numbers like `444`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that matches numbers from 31 to 99999, which you can adjust to your needs:

`^(?:[3][1-9]|[4-9][0-9]|(^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}$))$`
where

- `[3][1-9]` - matches numbers from 31 to 39
- `[4-9][0-9]` - matches numbers from 40 to 99
- `^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` - matches numbers from 100 to 9999

The last bit `^[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` can be changed to `^[1-9][0-9]{2,}` to match any number greater than 100

Comment: Doesn't work when leading zeros are present

Comment: It would be also a complete different requirement than 31 to 99999. My example was not meant to do it. As a solution: you can add a group at the beginning of this regex that would allow any number of 0s in front. Other solution (if zeros are not important - to remove zeros before parsing).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed the number to be greater than 59. And this worked for me.

```
[6-9][0-9]+|[1-9]\d{2,}
```

**EDIT**

This also works.

```
[6-9][0-9]|[1-9]\d{2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but none of these expressions worked for me (maybe it's because I'm on PHP). The following expression worked fine to validate that a number is higher than 49:

```
/([5-9][0-9])|([1-9]\d{3}\d*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since writing regular expressions for numbers is very error-prone, one could use the "[Trie Regex System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/15096247)" to generate a regex for **small numbers** or a **small range** of numbers

```
import re


class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def add(self, word):
        ref = self.data
        for char in word:
            ref[char] = char in ref and ref[char] or {}
            ref = ref[char]
        ref[""] = 1

    def dump(self):
        return self.data

    def quote(self, char):
        return char

    def _pattern(self, pData):
        data = pData
        if "" in data and len(data.keys()) == 1:
            return None

        alt = []
        cc = []
        q = 0
        for char in sorted(data.keys()):
            if isinstance(data[char], dict):
                try:
                    recurse = self._pattern(data[char])
                    alt.append(self.quote(char) + recurse)
                except:
                    cc.append(self.quote(char))
            else:
                q = 1
        cconly = not len(alt) > 0

        if len(cc) > 0:
            if len(cc) == 1:
                alt.append(cc[0])
            else:
                alt.append("[" + "".join(cc) + "]")

        if len(alt) == 1:
            result = alt[0]
        else:
            result = "(?:" + "|".join(alt) + ")"

        if q:
            if cconly:
                result += "?"
            else:
                result = "(?:%s)?" % result
        return result

    def pattern(self):
        return self._pattern(self.dump()).replace("\\-", "-")


def number_between(start, end, fullnumberreplacement="\\d"):
    r"""
    Generate a regular expression to match numbers within a specified range.

    Args:
        start (int): The start of the range.
        end (int): The end of the range.
        fullnumberreplacement (str): Replacement for digits (0-9) in the regular expression pattern.

    Returns:
        str: The regular expression pattern to match numbers within the specified range.
    """
    tree = Trie()
    if start >= 0 and end >= 0:
        for x in range(start, end):
            tree.add(str(x))
        return (
            "(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + ")\\b)"
        )
    if start < 0 and end < 0:
        for x in range(start, end):
            tree.add(str(-x))
        return (
            "(?:(?:-\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + ")\\b)"
        )
    if start < 0 and end >= 0:
        for x in range(start, 0):
            tree.add(str(-x))
        re1 = (
            "(?:-(?:\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + ")\\b)"
        )
        tree2 = Trie()
        for x in range(0, end):
            tree2.add(str(x))
        re2 = (
            "(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:"
            + tree2.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + ")\\b)"
        )
        return f"{re1}|{re2}"
    else:
        for x in range(start, end):
            tree.add(str(-x))
        return (
            "(?:\\b(?:"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + ")\\b)"
        )


def number_ge(n, fullnumberreplacement="\\d"):
    r"""
    Generate a regular expression to match numbers greater than or equal to a specified value.

    Args:
        n (int): The value to compare against.
        fullnumberreplacement (str): Replacement for digits (0-9) in the regular expression pattern.

    Returns:
        str: The regular expression pattern to match numbers greater than or equal to the specified value.
    """
    if n >= 0:
        number_of_digits = len(str(n))
        tree = Trie()
        for x in range(n, int("1" + "0" * number_of_digits)):
            tree.add(str(x))
        return (
            "(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + f"\\b))|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]{fullnumberreplacement}{{{number_of_digits},}}\\b))"
        )
    else:
        tree = Trie()
        for x in range(n, 0):
            tree.add(str(-x))
        return (
            "(?:-(?:\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + f"\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]{fullnumberreplacement}{{0,}}\\b))"
        )


def number_le(n, fullnumberreplacement="\\d"):
    r"""
    Generate a regular expression to match numbers less than or equal to a specified value.

    Args:
        n (int): The value to compare against.
        fullnumberreplacement (str): Replacement for digits (0-9) in the regular expression pattern.

    Returns:
        str: The regular expression pattern to match numbers less than or equal to the specified value.
    """
    if n < 0:
        number_of_digits = len(str(n)) - 1
        tree = Trie()
        for x in range(-n, int("1" + "0" * (number_of_digits - 1) + "1")):
            tree.add(str(x))
        return (
            "(?:-(?:\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + f"\\b))|(?:-\\b[1-9]{fullnumberreplacement}{{{number_of_digits},}}\\b)"
        )

    else:
        number_of_digits = len(str(n)) - 1
        tree = Trie()
        for x in range(n, 0, -1):
            tree.add(str(x))
        return (
            "(?:(?:\\b"
            + tree.pattern().replace("[0123456789]", fullnumberreplacement)
            + f"\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:-\\b[1-9]{fullnumberreplacement}{{0,}}\\b)"
        )

# Code to test if the results are right
import random

for _ in range(5):
    start = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    end = random.randint(1002, 2000)
    regex = number_between(start=start, end=end, fullnumberreplacement="\\d")
    print(f"{regex=}\n")
    regexcompiled = re.compile(regex)
    for x in range(5):
        randomint = random.randint(-(start * 2), end * 2)
        regexresults = regexcompiled.findall(str(randomint))
        print(f"""start: {start} end: {end} number:{randomint} / {regexresults=}""")
        isbetween = randomint >= start and randomint < end
        anyfound = any(regexresults)
        assert isbetween == anyfound

for _ in range(5):
    n = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    ge_regex = number_ge(n=n, fullnumberreplacement="\\d")
    le_regex = number_le(n=n, fullnumberreplacement="\\d")
    print(f"{ge_regex=}\n")
    print(f"{le_regex=}\n")

    biggerthan = re.compile(ge_regex)
    lessthen = re.compile(le_regex)
    start = random.randint(-1000, 1000)
    end = random.randint(1002, 2000)
    for x in range(5):
        randomint = random.randint(-(start * 2), end * 2)
        regexresultsbigger_or_equal = biggerthan.findall(str(randomint))
        regexresultslessthan_or_equal = lessthen.findall(str(randomint))
        print(
            f"""n:{n} test:{randomint} bigger or equal: {regexresultsbigger_or_equal} less or equal: {regexresultslessthan_or_equal}"""
        )
        isbigger = randomint >= n
        islessthan = randomint <= n
        anyfoundbigger = any(regexresultsbigger_or_equal)
        anyfoundlessthan = any(regexresultslessthan_or_equal)
        assert isbigger == anyfoundbigger
        assert islessthan == anyfoundlessthan
    print(f"""start: {start} end: {end} number:{randomint} / {regexresults=}""")
```

Looking at the results, it should be clear why it's not a good idea to use it with big numbers. The generated regexes are huge (but fast)

```
regex='(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:(?:1(?:0(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|1(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6[012]))|7(?:8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)))\\b)'

start: 780 end: 1163 number:1947 / regexresults=[]
start: 780 end: 1163 number:293 / regexresults=[]
start: 780 end: 1163 number:543 / regexresults=[]
start: 780 end: 1163 number:1498 / regexresults=[]
start: 780 end: 1163 number:794 / regexresults=['794']
regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3[012345]?|[456789]))?|8\\d?|9\\d?))\\b)|(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:(?:1(?:(?:0(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|8(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|9(?:(?:0[012345678]?|[123456789]))?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|8(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|9(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|0))\\b)'

start: -735 end: 1909 number:1733 / regexresults=['1733']
start: -735 end: 1909 number:2472 / regexresults=[]
start: -735 end: 1909 number:2679 / regexresults=[]
start: -735 end: 1909 number:1852 / regexresults=['1852']
start: -735 end: 1909 number:2405 / regexresults=[]
regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8[012345678]?|9))?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))\\b)|(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:(?:1(?:(?:0(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3[0123]?|[456789]))?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|8(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|9(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|0))\\b)'

start: -588 end: 1034 number:1595 / regexresults=[]
start: -588 end: 1034 number:1870 / regexresults=[]
start: -588 end: 1034 number:1935 / regexresults=[]
start: -588 end: 1034 number:1337 / regexresults=[]
start: -588 end: 1034 number:1184 / regexresults=[]
regex='(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:(?:1(?:0(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|1(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7[012345678]))|4(?:2[56789]|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|5(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|6(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|7(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)))\\b)'

start: 425 end: 1179 number:1441 / regexresults=[]
start: 425 end: 1179 number:543 / regexresults=['543']
start: 425 end: 1179 number:-264 / regexresults=[]
start: 425 end: 1179 number:-461 / regexresults=[]
start: 425 end: 1179 number:-38 / regexresults=[]
regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9[012345678]?))?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))\\b)|(?:(?<!-)\\b(?:(?:1(?:(?:0(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4[0123]?|[56789]))?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|8(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|9(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|0))\\b)'

start: -698 end: 1444 number:1950 / regexresults=[]
start: -698 end: 1444 number:2542 / regexresults=[]
start: -698 end: 1444 number:2330 / regexresults=[]
start: -698 end: 1444 number:1489 / regexresults=[]
start: -698 end: 1444 number:1626 / regexresults=[]
ge_regex='(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b(?:7(?:8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d))\\b))|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]\\d{3,}\\b))'

le_regex='(?:(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|80?|9))?|8\\d?|9\\d?)\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:-\\b[1-9]\\d{0,}\\b)'

n:780 test:3 bigger or equal: [] less or equal: ['3']
n:780 test:2019 bigger or equal: ['2019'] less or equal: []
n:780 test:1344 bigger or equal: ['1344'] less or equal: []
n:780 test:1429 bigger or equal: ['1429'] less or equal: []
n:780 test:1505 bigger or equal: ['1505'] less or equal: []
start: 719 end: 1201 number:1505 / regexresults=[]
ge_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|4(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|5(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|6(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|7(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|8(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|9(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3[01234]?|[456789]))?)\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]\\d{0,}\\b))'

le_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1000|9(?:3[456789]|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d))\\b))|(?:-\\b[1-9]\\d{3,}\\b)'

n:-934 test:2523 bigger or equal: ['2523'] less or equal: []
n:-934 test:2146 bigger or equal: ['2146'] less or equal: []
n:-934 test:2327 bigger or equal: ['2327'] less or equal: []
n:-934 test:2643 bigger or equal: ['2643'] less or equal: []
n:-934 test:1985 bigger or equal: ['1985'] less or equal: []
start: -954 end: 1323 number:1985 / regexresults=[]
ge_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|3(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|[56789]))?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?)\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]\\d{0,}\\b))'

le_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1000|3(?:49|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|4(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|5(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|6(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|7(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d))\\b))|(?:-\\b[1-9]\\d{3,}\\b)'

n:-349 test:2268 bigger or equal: ['2268'] less or equal: []
n:-349 test:3065 bigger or equal: ['3065'] less or equal: []
n:-349 test:2506 bigger or equal: ['2506'] less or equal: []
n:-349 test:1436 bigger or equal: ['1436'] less or equal: []
n:-349 test:3478 bigger or equal: ['3478'] less or equal: []
start: -309 end: 1815 number:3478 / regexresults=[]
ge_regex='(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b(?:2(?:3[89]|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|3(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|4(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|5(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|6(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|7(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d))\\b))|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]\\d{3,}\\b))'

le_regex='(?:(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3[012345678]?|[456789]))?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?)\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:-\\b[1-9]\\d{0,}\\b)'

n:238 test:1572 bigger or equal: ['1572'] less or equal: []
n:238 test:1219 bigger or equal: ['1219'] less or equal: []
n:238 test:1529 bigger or equal: ['1529'] less or equal: []
n:238 test:1128 bigger or equal: ['1128'] less or equal: []
n:238 test:1117 bigger or equal: ['1117'] less or equal: []
start: -308 end: 1169 number:1117 / regexresults=[]
ge_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2\\d?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?))?|2(?:(?:0\\d?|1\\d?|2[01]?|[3456789]))?|3\\d?|4\\d?|5\\d?|6\\d?|7\\d?|8\\d?|9\\d?)\\b))|(?:\\b0\\b)|(?:(?<!-)(?:\\b[1-9]\\d{0,}\\b))'

le_regex='(?:-(?:\\b(?:1000|2(?:2[123456789]|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|3(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|4(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|5(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|6(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|7(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|8(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d)|9(?:0\\d|1\\d|2\\d|3\\d|4\\d|5\\d|6\\d|7\\d|8\\d|9\\d))\\b))|(?:-\\b[1-9]\\d{3,}\\b)'

n:-221 test:2512 bigger or equal: ['2512'] less or equal: []
n:-221 test:2415 bigger or equal: ['2415'] less or equal: []
n:-221 test:2002 bigger or equal: ['2002'] less or equal: []
n:-221 test:1327 bigger or equal: ['1327'] less or equal: []
n:-221 test:1620 bigger or equal: ['1620'] less or equal: []
start: -600 end: 1751 number:1620 / regexresults=[]
```