# Regex for numbers 1-25

Tags: regex

I am working on a music generation project. Input only contains alpha characters and digits. The regex is one of the requirements we've set as a limitation.

So, this gets me numbers under 26 but if a number like 27 shows up it still picks up the 2 and the 7.  How can I exclude all numbers 26 and up?   Thanks!

```
/[0-2][0-5]|[1-9]/g
```

I should add...this is part of a large string with letters and spaces before and after the numbers.  So I have to recognize the numbers in the string and pull them out.  Only using string.prototype.match() and regex.  Long story.  Thx

Comment: I guess you can't do that, but will be easier work with it's numeric value rather than simply text. Anyway read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592488/regex-how-can-i-match-all-numbers-greater-than-49

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on all option.  Need to use regex unfortunately.  Not my choice.  Thanks though

Comment: How is the input data structured? Are the numbers separated by a special character (e. g. is there at least one space between the numbers)?

Comment: @Fedreg: See [my answer with explanations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39138675/3832970).

Comment: `\b(1?\d|2[0-5])\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `[0-2][0-5]|[1-9]` regex pattern matches any sequence of a `0-2` digit followed with `0-5` digit OR a `1-9` digit *anywhere* inside the string.

To match *individual* values from `1` till `25`, you may use

```
/\b(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF9dG0/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])` - either of the alternatives:

  - `0?[1-9]` - an optional leading `0` followed with a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `1[0-9]` - `10` till `19`
  - `2[0-5]` - `20` till `25`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

Comment: Wiktor, thank you for the explanations.  The problem is that there will be spaces before and after the numbers.  I'm sorry if I did not make that clear and wasted your time.  Have only used regex sparingly and didn't realize this would be so complex.  I will re-edit my post

Comment: So, you are extracting them? Replace `^` and `$` with `\b`. If there are other issues, feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: That did it!  Again, sorry for lack of clarity!

Comment: You know, that is not a perfect solution if your input is a mess. If there are dates or float values or version numbers, you would probably like to exclude those, and that means, you'd have to use something like `/(?:^|[^\d.])(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])(?![.\d])/g` and use the `RegExp#exec` in a loop to get the capture group contents out of each match. This won't match  `2` in `2. Text` though, so further adjustments might be necessary.

Comment: No, it is a music generation project.  Only alpha characters and digits.  It is just a bit of an experiment and regex is one of the requirements we've set as a limitation.  If it expands we will surely use a better method that regex.  Your answer was very helpful though

Comment: You can also match leading 0 (zero or more) with the * quantifier: `/\b(0*[1-9]|0*1[0-9]|0*2[0-3])\b/g`. This will match 22 and 0022, if for you it's the same number.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh... so you have right now... 0-5, 10-15, 20-25 OR 0-9

You had the right idea, just wrong application of the idea.

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-5])

// should omit those pesky one-offs you're seeing as mentioned in the comments.
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-5])$
\b([01]?[0-9]|2[0-5])\b

// if you also want to exclude 0...
^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$
\b([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])\b
```

That figuratively says any number between 0 thru 19(w/ or w/o preleading 0's) OR 20-25.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I see...thanks for explaining.  this seems to work up until 19 but returns 20-25 as individual integers ( 2,0   2, 5 etc.  ). Sadly I have to use regex for this.

Comment: ^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-5])$ or leading/trailing \b

Comment: Steve, thanks.  I edited my post to note that there could be preceding and following spaces.  Apologies for not including that originally.  Didn't realize it would matter; new to regex.

Comment: So the \b would be ideal for you. I write complex regex's to parse thru logs to find important troubleshooting methods on unix/linux hosts at work. \b is a barrier... like a white space. Meaning this should be an isolated finding next to other stuff.

Comment: Ya I'll remember that \b for next time!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along the lines of (take or remove some of the elements I added as I don't know your exact requirements)

```
/^(([ 01]?[1-9])|2[0-5])$/
```

- The `^...$` to match the entire input to avoid matching single digits of a two-digit input
- `?` to allow for a one-digit input
- the `|` to allow for the two cases "first digit = 0 or 1" and "first digit = 2"

But over all there certainly are better tools than regex to do this job, like parsing the number and doing a simple comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`^\d$|^1\d$|^2[0-6]$` will match 0-26.

However, this is not a problem you should be solving with regex. A better solution is to test the number with operators like `<` or `<=`:

```
myNum < 27 // is 0-26
```