# Regular expression range 1 25

Tags: regex

Hello can someone help me creating a regex for numeric range from 1 to 25, I wouldn't like 01 02 etc just 1 2 3 ....
Thanks
My failed attempt `/^([1-2]{1,2}[0-9])$/`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138073 (not a dupe, since it allows for leading zeroes)

Answer (score 4):

This is the **"simple to understand"** way

`/^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$/`

Breakdown:-

- `|`: or operator
- `[1-9]`: match 1 to 9
- `1[0-9]`: match 10 to 19
- `2[0-5]`: match 20 to 25