# How to check if multiple substrings appear together in a string

Tags: python, list

```
strings = ['I have a bird', 'I have a bag and a bird', 'I have a bag']
words = ['bird','bag']
```

I want to find the string that includes both bird and bag in the list `strings`, regardless of order. So the result for only the second element in `strings` should be true and the rest should be false.

The output I want:

```
False
True
False
```

`words` do not necessarily need to be stored in list, and I know that `regex` could do a similar thing but I would prefer to use other ways than `regex` because my words are mandarin chinese which requires some complicated use of regex than english.

Comment: The nested-for loop solutions are fine but they don't scale well.  If you have huge amount of text and your text or query words are related by common prefixes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628742/find-lots-of-string-in-text-python/43629194) may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strings = ['I have a bird', 'I have a bag and a bird', 'I have a bag']
words = ['bird','bag']


for string in strings:
  stringlist = string.split()
  word1 , word2 = words
  if word1 in stringlist and word2 in stringlist:
    print(True)
  else:
    print(False)
```

**Result**

False
True
False

Comment: I now get how things work, thanks! I didn't know I needed to split the strings before I try to find the words within the string.

Answer (score 8):

List comprehension will work combined with the `all` function:

```
[all([k in s for k in words]) for s in strings]
```

This results in the following on your example:

```
[False, True, False]
```

Comment: `[all(word in sentence for word in words) for sentence in strings] `  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
for substring in strings:
    k = [ w for w in words if w in substring ]
    print (len(k) == len(words) )
```

Comment: I would prefer this one but it only resulted in false false?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your initial question - but i've fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use of **function all()** would be best option here, but point is doing **without for loop**.
Here is solution using **map/lambda function**.

```
strings = ['I have a bird', 'I have a bag and a bird', 'I have a bag']
words = ['bird','bag']
map(lambda x: all(map(lambda y:y in x.split(),words)),strings)
```

output would be:

```
[False, True, False]
```

However, **Naive Solution** is for beginner:

```
for string in strings:
    count_match=0
    for word in words:
        if word in string.split():
            count_match+=1
    if(count_match==len(words)):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

And output would be :

```
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

For variable number of words, without using the split function.

```
strings = ['I have a bird', 'I have a bag and a bird', 'I have a bag']
words = ['bird','bag']

 for string in strings:
    print(all(word in string for word in words))
```