# Filter list of strings using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
>>> li = ["a b self", "mpilgrim", "foo c", "b", "c", "b", "d", "d"]
>>> condition = ["b", "c", "d"]
>>> [elem for elem in li if elem in condition]
['b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

But is there a way to return

```
['a b self','foo c','b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'd']
```

Since b and c are included in `'a b self'` and `'foo c'`, I want the code to return the two as well.

Comment: What if `condition = ['d', 'e', 'f']`?  Would you say that "e" and "f" are _included_ in "a b self" and "foo c"?

Comment: @DSM no I would not, I'm just interested in the elements between blanks

Comment: Will you ever need to worry about an entry in `condition` having spaces of its own?  For example, would you ever need to look for `"a b"` and want it to be found in `"a b self"` but not in `"a banana"`?

Comment: No that won't be a problem. In your example I would be looking for 'a' and 'b ' in 'a b self' and 'a' in 'a bannana'. Elements in conditions do not have spaces they are all non-spaced strings (i.e single words)

Comment: thanks, that means that the updated version of Elisha's answer should work for you, I think.

Comment: If you're looking for performance, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42742810/6419007) might interest you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the code needs to retrieve all the strings that contain any of the conditions strings:

```
[elem for elem in li if any(c in elem for c in condition)]
```

In case a full match of a condition is required:

```
[elem for elem in li if
 any(re.search('(^|\s){}(\s|$)'.format(c), elem) for c in condition)]
```

**Edit**: This can be simplified to a single pre-defined regex:

```
predicate = re.compile('(^|\s)({})(\s|$)'.format('|'.join(condition)))

[elem for elem in li if predicate.search(elem)]
```

Comment: Nice answer I like it

Comment: ;-)  I was going to propose using `\b` if we were going a regex route.

Comment: I realized this would be more precise : [elem for elem in li if any(c in elem.split() for c in condition)]

Comment: @song0089, you're right, the split approach is more straightforward :)

Comment: Yes, a `split` is required. Also, a Regex union would be a better idea than `n` distinct regexen.

Comment: Or `if set(elem.split()).intersection(condition)`.  But that doesn't generalize as well to the case in which conditions might have spaces too (although OP isn't interested in those.)

Comment: Also, you could just use `'\b'` for word boundaries.

Comment: @EricDuminil @DSM, wouldn't `\b` include other strings? In the case of `r'\ba\b'`, wouldn't it match also `'a.'`?

Comment: Yes it would. Only OP knows what's the desired behaviour :)