# Pandas string search - multiple exact values - very slow

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

Using Pandas, I am taking a large CSV file, and only want rows that contain certain exact strings.  I have this working but feel there should be a better way as it is very slow and difficult to maintain the search patterns as I add more terms to search.  Here is the code snippet:

```
regex_search = '(?:\,|^)EXACT PATTERN 1(?:\,|$)|(?:\,|^)EXACT PATTERN 2(?:\,|$)'
results = df[df['Column_to_search'].str.contains(regex_search)]
#now spit out all the rows where the column had the matched value in new CSV file
```

The regex I am using basically says:

```
(?:\,|^)  --> pattern must be preceded by a comma
(?:\,|$)  --> pattern must be followed by a comma
|         --> OR ,so that I can match as many search terms as needed
#...
#df is just the data frame that was loaded via pandas
```

This list causes a lot of problems for maintenance!  I have to take the list and run it through a loop to add the regex strings, and then have to format any new phrases as they are needed.

Originally, I had the search term as:

```
regex_search = 'EXACT PATTERN 1|EXACT PATTERN 2'
```

This is easier to maintain but this causes problems because it is regex it will also match a ton of false positives, especially for smaller phrases or acronyms.

The regex_search variable usually has 300+ phrases to search and the csv files have thousands of rows.  Is there a python function to do this?  Maybe something like:

```
.str.match_multiple()
#or
regex_search_list = ['ABC','XYZ','ETC']
.str.match_in_list(regex_search_list)
```

I don't think I can use .match because my regex string has multiple values.  If there is a way for pandas to match column values based upon a list, I haven't found it yet.

Thoughts?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking if pandas can search a column for a list of values? `df[df.column_name.isin(list_of_values)]` It has to be an exact match.

Comment: From what I have tested, the `str` accessor isn't faster than using a for loop in Python. That might give you a small speed up. Then I would suggest checking out [cython](http://cython.org/).

Comment: The problem with this alternation based regex is that each alternative matches at the same location.  Use `(?:,|^)(?:patt1|patt2|pattN)(?:,|$)`. Also, the alternation in the beginning and end can be made up for using `(?<![^,])` and `(?![^,])` (not sure if it is faster). Then, you may use [trie to build an efficient regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970)

Comment: A.Kot:  wow.  .isin() is sooo much faster!  And it is much easier to manage as everything is in a list.  I think 

Wiktor:  I haven't tried your solution yet, and might not need to because .isin works so well, but good call, I think you are right that this would be way better than my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to A.Kot in comments, i used .isin() and it took my script from 20 minutes to about 10 seconds.

New code :

```
list_search = ['EXACT PATTERN 1', 'EXACT PATTERN 2']
results = df[df['Column_to_search'].isin(list_search)]
```