# Get Response from Existing Google Spreadsheet, Append Rows and Update

Tags: python, google-sheets

I can connect to a Google Spreadsheet and add new rows (actual values from a list) as shown below and it works:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

#Name of Spreadsheet
Sheet_Title = "New Spreadsheet Final"

# The ID of the spreadsheet 
spreadsheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
#Get sheet ID

#Open the wanted Tab
sheet = gc.open(Sheet_Title).worksheet("Tab One")  

#Get the wanted range of the sheet
range_name = 'A1:W1000'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

#Add new rows in the Sheet. Values are hardcoded below
values = [
    ['09/01/2021', 'IT', '8%'],
    ['08/02/2021', 'NL', '1%']
    # Additional rows ...
]
body = {
    'values': values
}

#Append the rows in the Google Spreadsheet
result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
```

and what I am trying to do now is to add new rows but for each cells (or generally specific columns) add a data validation. So, I went down and checked the response. I then appended a new row value that includes the format and the data validation:

```
#Values to be added in the original query
value_to_be_added = [
              {
                "formattedValue": "05/05/2019",
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "DATE",
                    "pattern": "dd/mm/yyyy"
                  }
                },
                "dataValidation": {
                  "condition": {
                    "type": "DATE_IS_VALID"
                  },
                  "strict": "True"
                }
              },
              {
                "formattedValue": "DE",
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "NUMBER",
                    "pattern": "#,##0.00"
                  },
                  "verticalAlignment": "BOTTOM"
                },
                "dataValidation": {
                  "condition": {
                    "type": "ONE_OF_LIST",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "UK"
                      },
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "ES"
                      },
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "IT"
                      },
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "DE"
                      },
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "AT"
                      },
                      {
                        "userEnteredValue": "NL"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "showCustomUi": "True"
                }
              },
              {
                "formattedValue": "4%",
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "PERCENT",
                    "pattern": "0%"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
```

In other words, I have tried manipulating the original response JSON and the only thing I need is to update the full file but I cannot find the correct update function:

```
#Get request to get the full Google Spreadsheet in a JSON
request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=range_name, includeGridData=True)
response = request.execute()

#dictionary that will be appended in the values of the response
mydict = {}

#Assign dictionary with the new value. We have one value in this case.
mydict[row_count+1] = value_to_be_added

#print(mydict[row_count+1])

#Add new row in the response.
response['sheets'][0]['data'][0]['rowData'][x]['values'].append(mydict[row_count+1])

#updated response that has to be sent/updated in the API.
new_response = response
```

Is there a way to fully update/replace the original response with the updated one?

The original Spreadsheet:

[image]

The final Spreadsheet after my update.request (how I want it to be):

[image]

where you can see one new row with the data validation applying (it can be an X amount of rows).

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want? By this, I would like to think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to append a row to the next row of the last row of Spreadsheet.

  - You want to append a row like the date value of `dd/mm/yyyy`, the data validation, the number of `0%` format and the number.
  - You want to put the values of `05/05/2019, UK, 8%, 9` as the display values.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this sample script, I used the method of `batch_update` of gspread. The method of `batch_upate` of gspread is the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate of Sheets API. And the row is appended by the appendCells request.

#### Sample script:

The sample script is as follows. Before you run the script, please set the Spreadsheet ID and sheet name. In this script, `Tab One` is used as the sheet name.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
sheetName = "Tab One"
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
body = {'requests':
        [
            {
                'appendCells':
                {
                    'rows':
                    [
                        {
                            'values':
                            [
                                {
                                    'userEnteredFormat':
                                    {
                                        'numberFormat':
                                        {
                                            'type': 'DATE',
                                            'pattern': 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'dataValidation':
                                    {
                                        'condition':
                                        {
                                            'type': 'DATE_IS_VALID'
                                        },
                                        'strict': True
                                    },
                                    'userEnteredValue':
                                    {
                                        'numberValue': 43590  # This is the serial number of "05/05/2019".
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    'userEnteredFormat':
                                    {
                                        'numberFormat':
                                        {
                                            'type': 'NUMBER',
                                            'pattern': '#,##0.00'
                                        },
                                        'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM'
                                    },
                                    'dataValidation':
                                    {
                                        'condition':
                                        {
                                            'type': 'ONE_OF_LIST',
                                            'values':
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'UK'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'ES'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'IT'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'DE'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'AT'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'userEnteredValue': 'NL'
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        'showCustomUi': True
                                    },
                                    'userEnteredValue':
                                    {
                                        'stringValue': 'UK'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    'userEnteredFormat':
                                    {
                                        'numberFormat':
                                        {
                                            'type': 'PERCENT',
                                            'pattern': '0%'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'userEnteredValue':
                                    {
                                        'numberValue': 0.08
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    'userEnteredValue':
                                    {
                                        'numberValue': 9
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    'sheetId': sheetId,
                    'fields': '*'
                }
            }
        ]
        }
res = spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
print(res)
```

#### Note:

- When `05/05/2019` is put as the date of the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, please put the number of `43590` which is the serial number.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)

### Added:

When you want to use the request body in the for loop, how about the following script? The batchUpdate method can be used with an array.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
sheetName = "Tab One"
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
requests = []
for x in range(len(new_values)):  # Please set "new_values".
    body =                 {
                    'appendCells':
                    {
                        'rows':
                        [
                            {
                                'values':
                                [
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'DATE',
                                                'pattern': 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'dataValidation':
                                        {
                                            'condition':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'DATE_IS_VALID'
                                            },
                                            'strict': True
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][0]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'NUMBER',
                                                'pattern': '#,##0.00'
                                            },
                                            'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM'
                                        },
                                        'dataValidation':
                                        {
                                            'condition':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'ONE_OF_LIST',
                                                'values':
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'UK'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'ES'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'IT'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'DE'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'AT'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'NL'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            'showCustomUi': True
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'stringValue': new_values[x][1]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'PERCENT',
                                                'pattern': '0%'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][2]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][2]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        'sheetId': sheetId,
                        'fields': '*'
                    }
                }
    requests.append(body)

res = spreadsheet.batch_update({'requests':requests})
print(res)
```

Comment: That works and I am going to accept the answer. I am also going to post my version based on yours. There might be an easier way you can suggest.

Comment: @Apolo Radomer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I added one more sample script for your additional script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes. I can see you added that part. In my original script I have also converted the date to a 5-digit serial code and added everything into functions (although for a reason that doesn't make the script faster but cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

My version based on Tanaike's answer:

```
#List of rows with values
new_values = [[43590,'UK',0.08,9],[43590,'DE',0.07,8]]

#connect to the google sheet and tab
sheetName = "Tab One"
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']

#Add each value/row
for x in range(len(new_values)):
    #print(new_values[x])
    body = {'requests':
            [
                {
                    'appendCells':
                    {
                        'rows':
                        [
                            {
                                'values':
                                [
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'DATE',
                                                'pattern': 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'dataValidation':
                                        {
                                            'condition':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'DATE_IS_VALID'
                                            },
                                            'strict': True
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][0]  # This is the serial number of "05/05/2019".
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'NUMBER',
                                                'pattern': '#,##0.00'
                                            },
                                            'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM'
                                        },
                                        'dataValidation':
                                        {
                                            'condition':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'ONE_OF_LIST',
                                                'values':
                                                [
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'UK'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'ES'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'IT'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'DE'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'AT'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'userEnteredValue': 'NL'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            'showCustomUi': True
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'stringValue': new_values[x][1]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredFormat':
                                        {
                                            'numberFormat':
                                            {
                                                'type': 'PERCENT',
                                                'pattern': '0%'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][2]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'userEnteredValue':
                                        {
                                            'numberValue': new_values[x][3]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }

                        ],
                        'sheetId': sheetId,
                        'fields': '*'
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
    res = spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

where the body gets pulled in every loop. You comment any alternatives if you think this is not the best way (looping the body). It might be easier to have a loop and append the `values` array in the body object.

Comment: Regarding [your deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60545418/3832970), you could probably make use of [a regex trie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970).