# What could be the better approach for pattern match and replace in Python?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a flat file with terms and sentences. If any term is found in the sentence, I need to append |present (term|present). Basically, pattern match (case insensitive) and append |present. Also, we need to retain the same case as in the sentence. What approach would be feasible and faster in Python. I tried this using Oracle regex, this takes days to process 70k records.

Right now I am using the below code. Is there a better approach. And also with the current approach, it works fine for the 50 records but the df['words'] is empty when run for the entire 70k records. Not sure what the reason could be.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = {'term': ['Ford', 'EXpensive', 'TOYOTA', 'Mercedes Benz', 'electric', 'cars'],
        'sentence': ['Ford is less expensive than Mercedes Benz.' ,'toyota, hyundai mileage is good compared to ford','tesla is an electric-car','toyota too has electric cars','CARS','CArs are expensive.']
        }
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
df = DataFrame(df,columns= ['term','sentence'])

pattern = "|".join(f"\w*(?<![A-Za-z-;:,/|]){i}\\b" for i in df["term"])

df["words"]= df['sentence'].str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def replace_values(row):
    if len(row.words)>0:
        pat = r"(\b"+"|".join(row.words) +r")(\b)"
        row.sentence = re.sub(pat, "\\1|present\\2", row.sentence)
    return row

df = df.apply(replace_values, axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you noticed your `pattern`? It is extremely inefficient. Also, the terms can be space separated phrases, so your word boundary approach will work partially, without sorting the terms first. Eg. if you have both `Mercedes Benz` and `Mercedes`, then the former will never be matched.

Comment: Please explain why you chose `\w*(?<![A-Za-z-;:,/|])` and not a plain `\b`?

Comment: Just to make sure if the terms beside special characters like Cars; are considered while replacing.

Comment: So, basically, `\b(?:term1|term2)\b` should work after sorting.

Comment: Meaning add \b(?:term1|term2)\b as part of pattern?

Comment: No, build it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is very inefficient since it has many unanchored alternatives starting with an identical pattern that can backtrack a lot. Besides, the word boundaries that you want to use you also need to sort the terms by length in descending order to find the longest terms in case they overlap (like, say, `Merceded` and `Mercedes Benz`).

So, use

```
pattern = r'(?i)\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(sorted(df["term"],key=len,reverse=True)))
```

Or, if you have spcial chars in the terms,

```
pattern = r'(?i)(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(df["term"],key=len,reverse=True))))
```

and then

```
df["words"]= df["sentence"].str.findall(pattern)
df["sentence"].replace(pattern, r"\g<0>|present", inplace=True, regex=True)
```

The pattern will look like `(?i)\b(?:Mercedes Benz|EXpensive|electric|TOYOTA|Ford|cars)\b`, it will match - in a case insensitive way due to `(?i)` - whole words `Mercedes Benz`, `EXpensive`, `electric`, `TOYOTA`, `Ford`, `cars` and in `df["sentence"].str.findall(pattern)`, it will find all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern match and in `df["sentence"].replace(pattern, r"\g<0>|present", inplace=True, regex=True)`, all matches will be replaced with themselves (`\g<0>` is a backreference to the whole match) + `|present` appended to them.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try. Is there a way we can exclude replacement beside a couple of special characters? Say, we had a term way and sentence had four-way. The replacement should not happen as it's substring. or if the term is part of a URL https://ford.com. This just messes up the existing URLs.

Comment: @ABY That is a matter of what you consider a word boundary. If you want it to be any non-word char except a `-` on the left, just add `(?<!-)` after the first `\b`. If you need whitespace boundaries, use `r'(?i)(?<!\S)(?:{})(?!\S)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(df["term"],key=len,reverse=True))))`. Note that if you have thousands of terms, you need to create a [regex trie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970).

Comment: :) Your explanation was really helpful. Thanks again. I have posted another question (58428167) which is a slight modification from this. Appreciate any help, if possible.