# Mapping dictionary to partial string match in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
 ID       Code
ABCD      00FQ
JKFA    8LK9|4F5H
QWST    2RLA|R1T5&8LK9
```

I am trying to map a dictionary (where the values are `List`) to the individual elements of `Code`.

The dictionary looks like so:

```
d={'00FQ':"['A','B']", '8LK9':"['X']", '4F5H':"['U','Z']", '2RLA':"['H','K']", 'R1T5':"['B','G']" }
```

I want to map this dict to each element in the `Code` column separated by `|`.

The resulting df would look like so:

```
 ID       Code           Logic
ABCD      00FQ          ['A','B']
JKFA    8LK9|4F5H       ['X'] | ['U','Z']
QWST    2RLA|R1T5&8LK9  ['H','K'] | ['B','G'] & ['X']
```

Comment: @DanielMesejo Fixed, sry

Answer (score 4):

IIUC `split` + `replace` + `join`

```
s=df.Code.str.split('|',expand=True).replace(d).stack().groupby(level=0).agg('|'.join)
s
Out[205]: 
0              ['A','B']
1        ['X']|['U','Z']
2    ['H','K']|['B','G']
dtype: object
df['Logic']=s
```

Update

```
s=df.Code.str.split('|')
df['Logic']=['|'.join(d.get(y)for y in x) for x in s]
Out[229]: ["['A','B']", "['X']|['U','Z']", "['H','K']|['B','G']"]
```

Update `replace` Date 2019-11-18(After op changed the question)

```
df.Code.replace(d,regex=True)
Out[376]: 
0                    ['A','B']
1              ['X']|['U','Z']
2    ['H','K']|['B','G']&['X']
Name: Code, dtype: object
```

Comment: I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling Python object`. Attempts to increase the capacity of the stack doing `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` causes it to crash after a while

Comment: @MaxB your Code have a long string ?

Comment: yes some of the list values in the dictionary may have a large number of elements

Comment: Then I recommend for loop :-)

Comment: I'm assuming those are two separate lines of code. When trying to execute `['|'.join(d.get(y)for y in x) for x in s]` I get the following error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: @MaxB `s=df.Code.str.split('|')` this is the new s

Comment: Yes I tried the exact updated code you provided and the TypeError still happens

Comment: @MaxB I am not sure what you need now, seems like you just need a replace , I have update the solution

Comment: I did not downvote, sry to change question so much I add bounty to make up for it:). doing replace raises the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @MaxB I am following your sample , and all my solutions work fine with your sample data and yield the expected output , so kindly compare the sample data with your real data frame to see the different

Comment: could this be caused by me using old pandas version? (23.4)

Comment: @MaxB I do not think so , BTW The dict should be d={'00FQ':"['A','B']", '8LK9':"['X']", '4F5H':"['U','Z']", '2RLA':"['H','K']", 'R1T5':"['B','G']"
}

Comment: thank you, question updated. My data is the exact same format (just a few more combinations). will troubleshoot. thank u for help will award bounty and delete comments tmrw.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['ABCD', '00FQ'], ['JKFA', '8LK9|4F5H'], ['QWST', '2RLA|R1T5&8LK9']], columns=['ID', 'Code'])

d = {'00FQ': "['A','B']", '8LK9': "['X']", '4F5H': "['U','Z']", '2RLA': "['H','K']", 'R1T5': "['B','G']"}


def r(w, d=d):
    """Function to be used for dictionary based replacement"""
    return d[w.group()]
```

**Code**

```
df['Logic'] = df['Code'].str.replace('[^|&]+', r).str.replace('([|&])', r' \1 ')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     ID            Code                          Logic
0  ABCD            00FQ                      ['A','B']
1  JKFA       8LK9|4F5H              ['X'] | ['U','Z']
2  QWST  2RLA|R1T5&8LK9  ['H','K'] | ['B','G'] & ['X']
```

The idea is first to replace everything that is not `|` or `&` by it's corresponding value in the dictionary (using the function `r`). Once this is done replace every `|` or `&` (using a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#grouping)) by itself surrounded by spaces (`r' \1 ')`.

Notice that in the first call to replace the `repl` parameter is a function (callable), this can be done as specified in the linked documentation:

> The callable is passed the regex match object and must return a
>   replacement string to be used. See re.sub().

*Note:* This solution assumes every possible code is in the dictionary used for replacement, if that is not the case change `r`  to:

```
def r(w, d=d):
    """Function to be used for dictionary based replacement"""
    return d.get(w.group(), w.group())
```

For more on regular expressions, see:

1. [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto)
2. [Speed up millions of regex replacements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3)

Comment: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` which is confusing because I have verified that the column is absolutely type `str`

Comment: @MaxB Did the error occur with the setup provided in the answer?

Comment: It did, I tried simplifying the df down to only one element as well.

Comment: Could you try: `df['Logic'] = df['Code'].astype(str).str.replace('[^|&]+', r).astype(str).str.replace('([|&])', r' \1 ')` instead?

Comment: I tried this and it works, but i get `'nan'` in each row for `df['Logic']`