# Replace exact substrings in a column based on a table / list / dataframe in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df, where one column has a string in it:

```
columnA
'PSX - Judge A::PSK-Ama'
'VSC - Jep::VSC-Da'
'VSO - Jep::VSO-Da'
...
```

And I have another dataframe, where I have the new strings:

```
old new
PSX PCC
VSO VVV
```

My desired outcome would be:

```
columnA
'PCC - Judge A::PCC-Ama'
'VSC - Jep::VSC-Da'
'VVV - Jep::VVV-Da'
...
```

My idea would be to write:

```
import re
df['columnA'] = df.replace('PSX', 'PCC', regex=True)
df['columnA'] = df.replace('VSO', 'VVV', regex=True)
```

for two replacements it is ok, but how to do it for severel replacements? Is there a smarter way to do it?

The dataframe you get here (thx to Daniel):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['PSX - Judge A::PSK-Ama',
                        'VSC - Jep::VSC-Da',
                        'VSO - Jep::VSO-Da'], columns=['columnA'])
replace = pd.DataFrame(data=[['PSX', 'PCC'],
                             ['VSO', 'VVV']], columns=['old', 'new'])
```

Comment: How about a for loop?

Comment: Hm..any vectorize solution ?

Comment: It is always single word replacement?

Comment: Why did not you involve "another dataframe" ? What's the sense of mentioning it?

Comment: It is always this type of replacement, so single word yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that the replacement parameter can be a function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['PSX - Judge A::PSK-Ama',
                        'VSC - Jep::VSC-Da',
                        'VSO - Jep::VSO-Da'], columns=['columnA'])

replace = pd.DataFrame(data=[['PSX', 'PCC'],
                             ['VSO', 'VVV']], columns=['old', 'new'])

lookup = dict(zip(replace.old, replace.new))


def repl(w, lookup=lookup):
    return lookup.get(w.group(), w.group())


df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].str.replace('\w+', repl)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                  columnA
0  PCC - Judge A::PSK-Ama
1       VSC - Jep::VSC-Da
2       VVV - Jep::VVV-Da
```

The idea is to extract the words in `columnA` and if it matches one in lookup replace it. This is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747503/4001592), in which bench-marking shows this to be the more competitive approach.

Comment: This takes 1.26359 seconds in my case (only measured once)

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in df_map.iterrows():
    df['columnA'] = df.replace(row[0], row[1], regex=True)
```

Where `df_map` is your mapping `DataFrame`.

Comment: This takes 9.5315 seconds in my case (only measured once)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "replacement dictionary" out of your second dataframe and then iterate over the keys and values and meanwhile use `str.replace`. This solution should be quite fast:

```
replacements = dict(zip(df2['old'], df2['new']))

for k, v in replacements.items():
    df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].str.replace(k, v)
```

```
                  columnA
0  PCC - Judge A::PSK-Ama
1       VSC - Jep::VSC-Da
2       VVV - Jep::VVV-Da
```

Comment: This takes 3.5880 seconds in my case (only measured once)