# pandas apply column with regex string to other column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have dataframe with two columns:

```
col1           col2
"aaa bbb"      some_regex_str1
"zzz aaa"      some_regex_str2
"sda343das"    some_regex_str3
...
"999 aaa dsd"  some_regex_strN
```

the length of the dataframe can be anything between 10^6 - 10^7.

Currently,

I do:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda row: re.search(row['col2'], row['col1'], axis=1)
```

It is slow.

What is the more efficient way to do it?

EDIT:

I have created yo.py module with

```
import re


def run_regex(x):
    return re.search(x['col2'], x['col1'])
```

in main module I do:

```
from yo import run_regex

...

res = df.parallel_apply(run_regex)
```

but I still get

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'prepare_worker.<locals>.closure.<locals>.wrapper'
```

Comment: could you share a sample dataframe with expected output?

Comment: I have created sample dataframe. The question is about application of these regexes on these strings. I do not want to change the regexes itself and change reason why I apply it. I wonder about most efficient way of these regexes apply.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3) will be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [dask](https://dask.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize your apply manually or via [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel). Another option is to use more efficient regex lib like [hyperscan](https://python-hyperscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/) or [re2](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2/).

If your regex string is simple string (i.e. your problem is to search substring in string), you can use [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://pyahocorasick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If you have a lot of duplicated values in col2, this will be the best solution.

EDIT: I've added pandarallel example:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

def f(x):
    return re.search(x['a'], x['b']).group()

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': '11', 'b': '11'}
] * 100)

df.parallel_apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have tried pandarallel with regex but it complained. I will try to share the error.

Comment: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'prepare_worker.<locals>.closure.<locals>.wrapper'

Comment: ty. please see my edit comment. i sitll get the error.

Comment: I've added example to my answer.