# Match different patterns also use abbreviation dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a problem. I have a `text` which is a freetext. And a regex should regnoize `element` what is a pattern. Unfortunately for some `element`s there are abbrevation. So thats why I generated a abbrevation dict. Is there an option to also loop through the `dict`. If the element is inside the dict? That the abbrevation `ca` also does match.

Dataframe

```py
   customerId                text element  code
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2
3           3        This is a ca     cat     0
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import copy
import re
d = {
    "customerId": [1, 3, 3, 3],
    "text": ["Something with Cat", "That is a huge dog", "Hello agian", 'This is a ca'],
     "element": ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat'],
     "code": [9,8,7, 9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['code'] = df['element'].astype('category').cat.codes
print(df)

abbreviation = {
    "cat": {
        "abbrev1": "ca",
    },
} 


%%time

elements = df['element'].unique()
def f(x):
    match = 999
    for element in elements:
        elements2 = [element]
        y = bool(re.search(element, x['text'], re.IGNORECASE))
        #^ here
        if(y):
            #print(forwarder)
            match = x['code']
            #match = True
            break
    x['test'] = match
    return x
df['test'] = None
df = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1)
```

What I have

```py
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
3           3        This is a ca     cat     0   999
```

What I want

```py
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
3           3        This is a ca     cat     0     0
```

Comment: To be clear, should cat and dog be inverted in `element`, would there be no match in the first two rows or wouldn't it change anyhing?

Comment: @mozway if understand your questions right -  It wouldn't it change anything

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

One approach:

```
# create an inverse lookup dictionary for the abbreviations
lookup = {v.lower(): k for k, d in abbreviation.items() for _, v in d.items()}
elements = df['element'].unique()

# replace the abbreviations with the full words
normal = df["text"].str.replace(fr"\b({'|'.join(lookup.keys())})\b", lambda x: lookup[x.group().lower()], regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# then find the words in text with the full words
df["test"] = np.where(normal.str.contains(fr"\b({'|'.join(elements)})\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE), df["code"], 999)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   customerId                text element  code  test
0           1  Something with Cat     cat     0     0
1           3  That is a huge dog     dog     1     1
2           3         Hello agian   mouse     2   999
3           3        This is a ca     cat     0     0
```

### Full Explanation

The first step is to create a lookup dictionary for the abbreviations:

```
lookup = {v.lower(): k for k, d in abbreviation.items() for _, v in d.items()}
```

for the current example `lookup` points to the following value:

```
{'ca': 'cat'}
```

the second step is to use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the abbreviations with the full words:

```
normal = df["text"].str.replace(fr"\b({'|'.join(lookup.keys())})\b", lambda x: lookup[x.group().lower()], regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

the variable `normal` holds the value:

```
0    Something with Cat
1    That is a huge dog
2           Hello agian
3         This is a cat
Name: text, dtype: object
```

note that the second parameter for str.replace is a callable, a description of the functionality can be found in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **repl** str or callable Replacement string or a callable. The callable is passed the regex match object and must return a
> replacement string to be used. See re.sub().

finally use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to create a boolean mask and pass it to [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["test"] = np.where(normal.str.contains(fr"\b({'|'.join(elements)})\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE), df["code"], 999)
```

in other words if there is a match use the corresponding value in
`df["code"]` otherwise use `999` to signal no match was found.

### Note on performance

If the number of abbreviations is large and performance is an issue you could use [`trrex`](https://trrex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#working-with-pandas):

```
import trrex as tx

# replace the abbreviations with the full words
normal = df["text"].str.replace(tx.make(lookup.keys()), lambda x: lookup[x.group().lower()], regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# then find the words in text with the full words
df["test"] = np.where(normal.str.contains(tx.make(elements), flags=re.IGNORECASE), df["code"], 999)
```

Note that you need to install the library:

```
pip install trrex
```

See these answers ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635997/4001592) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728476/4001592)) for a detailed discussion on performance gains.

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the author of [trrex](https://github.com/mesejo/trex)

Comment: Interesting package ;)