# Find words in a list that match the input string using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

Imagine if there is a list of words like `words = ["hello","boy","cool"]` and a user input of a string `string = "helloboycool"`.

My question: Is there a way to use **Regular Expression** to find all the words in the "words" list that match a part of the input "string".

For example:
`list = ["123","hello","nice","red","boy"]` and `input = "helloniceboy"`. The input string has **no spaces**.

Using the "input" string as a search term for the **regular expression**, the output should be the words `["hello","nice","boy"]` in a list form.

**Yes, I know this could be done through simple loops. However, I just trying to work on a problem that I came across while doing my office work. So, it was worth asking this question to y'all.**
Also, thanks for all the answers. They are sure helpful insights. **Overlapping is fine**

I am fairly new to the regex thing in python.

Comment: I think you dont need regex for this task

Comment: No, it is not possible with a single regex since you may have overlapping matches starting at the same location inside the string.

Comment: easiest solution would be loop through list and check if it is in input return true otherwise return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to find overlapping matches, you can turn the list into a regular expression that uses `|` to match alternatives. Then use `re.findall()` to get all the matches.

```
import re

words = ["123","hello","nice","red","boy"]
string = "helloniceboy"
regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in words))
result = re.findall(regex, string)
```

`re.escape()` ensures that the words will be matched literally, even if they contain characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

If you do need to find overlapping matches, the other answer that uses `if word in input` in a loop will work better.

Comment: The examples are just thought up, in real life, the presence of overlapping matches starting at the same position in the string is common. This is not a solution and not a workaround.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The OP didn't describe the use case, it's not clear that overlapping matches are necessary.

Comment: OPs will never tell you every detail. From experience, I know this is not going to help anyone in real life. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970) is the best approach when one has a dynamic list of words and wants to look them up in some larger text.

Comment: I don't agree with your comment. I honestly believe this helps every programmer who has just started researching about regular expressions. And thanks for your insights on the question.

Answer (score 3):

Regex was made for finding things in *strings*, not lists.

I would suggest looping through the list and checking if each word is inside `string`:

```
words = ["123", "hello", "nice", "red", "boy"]
string = "helloboycool"
result = []
for word in words:
    if word in string:
        result.append(word)
print(result)
```

You *could* use regex for this, but I wouldn't suggest it - this is much cleaner and faster.

Here is a version with `list comprehension`:

```
words = ["123", "hello", "nice", "red", "boy"]
string = "helloboycool"
result = [word for word in words if word in string]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regex? It can be done easily like this:

```py
list = ["123", "hello", "red", "nice", "happy", "boy"]
input = "helloniceboy"

result = []
for i in list:
    if i in input:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

If it **has** to be regex, there is a built-in module called `re` which you can use.