# Pandas extract information which starts with [\s\d_/] and ends in [\s\d_/]

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, findall

I am trying to extract set of keywords such as ['lemon', 'apple', 'coconut'] etc. from the paths such as
"\var\prj\lemon_123\xyz",
"\var\prj\123_apple\coconut",
"\var\prj\lemonade\coconutapple",
"\var\prj\apple\lemon"

The expected output is little complex:

| Paths | MatchedKeywords |
| --- | --- |
| "/var/prj/lemon_123/xyz" | lemon |
| "/var/prj/123_apple/coconut" | apple, coconut |
| "/var/prj/lemonade/coconutapple" |  |
| "/var/prj/apple/lemon" | apple, lemon |

**keep in mind that the** third row does not have the exact word which start with /, \s, \d or _
thats why there is no match.
The regular expression is kind of like this: \s\d_/[\s\d_/].
I tried using:

`df['Paths'].str.findall(r'[^\s\d_/]lemon|apple|coconut[\s\d_/$]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

But it is still showing 'lemon' and 'coconut' in the third row.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try matching on word boundaries (`\b`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Paths'].str.findall(r'(?<![^\W_])(?:lemon|apple|coconut)(?![^\W_])').str.join(", ")
df['Paths'].str.findall(r'(?<![^\W\d_])(?:lemon|apple|coconut)(?![^\W\d_])').str.join(", ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tp2nXt/1) (and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/tp2nXt/2)), the regex matches

- `(?<![^\W_])` - a location that is not immediately preceded with a char other than a non-word char and an underscore (it is a left-hand word boundary with the `_` subtracted from it)
- `(?:lemon|apple|coconut)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the words inside the group
- `(?![^\W_])` - a location that is not immediately followed with a char other than a non-word char and an underscore (it is a right-hand word boundary with the `_` subtracted from it).

If you use `(?<![^\W\d_])` and `(?![^\W\d_])` your word boundaries will be *letter* boundaries, i.e. it will be `\b` with digits and underscore subtracted from it.
See the Python demo:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Paths":["/var/prj/lemon_123/xyz", "/var/prj/123_apple/coconut", "/var/prj/lemonade/coconutapple", "/var/prj/apple/lemon"]})
df['Paths'].str.findall(r'(?<![^\W_])(?:lemon|apple|coconut)(?![^\W_])').str.join(", ")
#  0             lemon
#  1    apple, coconut
#  2                  
#  3      apple, lemon
#  Name: Paths, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer.
This is now working correctly. But now I have tried it on 1000 different keywords like apple, coconut, lemon,.... etc.
So if I put 1000 keywords inside it findall(). It shows "NaN" in the output even though some of them matches.
How can I put 1000 different keywords inside it ?

Comment: @NayanDesale Use the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970). Let me know if you need help implementing it.

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor. This is really helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not correct for what you're looking to match, which is easy to see with visualization tools like https://regexper.com/ (no affiliation; just grabbed the top Google result).

You have: `[^\s\d_/]lemon|apple|coconut[\s\d_/$]`

[image: [^\s\d_/]lemon|apple|coconut[\s\d_/$]]

but likely want something like: `[\s\d_/](lemon|apple|coconut)[\s\d_/]`

[image]

Comment: Now it is only matching (finding) the first keyword only.
From the second row, it is only matching 'coconut' and not 'apple'.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have that backwards? The regex I shared should find `apple` but not `coconut` since coconut doesn't end with `[\s\d_/]`.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is finding apple and not coconut.
I am sorry for my wrong comment.
But how can we get both of them? and with that specific regex?