# Remove the trailing comma when format string with tuples

Tags: python

I'm doing string formatting with tuples:

```
a = (1,2,3)
s = f"something in {a}"
print(s)
```

```
'something in (1, 2, 3)'
```

Everything is fine until I encounter a single-element tuple, which gives:

```
a = (1,)
s = f"something in {a}"
```

```
'something in (1,)'
```

what I actually want is:

```
'something in (1)'
```

How do I make tuple string formatting behaves consistently and remove the trailing comma?

Comment: `type((1))` is `int`; `type((1,))` is `tuple`. Without trailing comma it's different type

Comment: @JL0PD Yeah, but how do I achieve the same formatting since I don't know what `a` will be like since it is served as a parameter in my own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your own formatting logic, e.g.

```py
a = (1,2,3)
s = ','.join([str(x) for x in a])
print(s)  # 1,2,3

a = (1,)
s = ','.join([str(x) for x in a])
print(s)  # 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
import re

tuple = (1,)
s = "something in "  + re.sub(r',(?=\))', '', str(tuple))
print(s)
```

Result:

```
something in (1)
```

You don't need any for loop etc.

Answer (score 1):

Python have 2 magic methods for formatting values: `__str__` and `__repr__`.

`__str__` may return any string, but `__repr__` must return string that can be passed to `eval` and recreate value. It's not required, but you **should** do it. `print` tries to use `__str__` if it's overriden, otherwise it uses `__repr__`. This means that you can use `eval(repr(some_value))` to clone value, because most builtin types have overridden `__repr__` properly. That's why you get trailing comma when formatting `(1,)`.

If you really want to format tuple without trailing comma then use

```py
def format_tuple(value):
    return "(" + ",".join(repr(v) for v in value) + ")"
# (1,) -> "(1)"
# () -> "()"
# (1, 2, 3,) -> "(1, 2, 3)"
# (1, 2, 3) -> "(1, 2, 3)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, tuples are string serialized such that they can be de-serialized back to the original form.

That means, tuples with only one element are serialized `(1,)` etc.

If all you want is to avoid this "exception", serialize tuples of length one differently

```py
for tp in [(1,2), ("1",)]:
  if len(tp) > 1:
    print(tp)
  else:
    s = str(tp)
    s = s[0:-2] + s[-1:]
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tim Biegeleisen's answer:

```
a = (1,)
s = f"something in ({','.join([str(x) for x in a])})"
print(s)
```

```
'something in (1)'
```

Comment: @Inputvector Great! But why `regular expression `  is superior to for-loop?

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3/42747503#42747503

Comment: @Inputvector Thanks! But in my case, performance isn't an issue for tuples are often less than 10 elements. I presume a for-loop combined with `f-string` might be more readable than a regular expression here. Thanks for showing me a great way of performance-boosting anyway!