# How to remove trailing comma from a tuple

Tags: sql, python-3.x, list, tuples

I need your advice and help on how to remove the trailing comma from a tuple. The whole purpose of removing the trailing comma from a tuple is because I'm trying to execute an update query statement to update some records in a table. My query contains/uses the IN function.

So basically, I have a list -> I convert the list to a tuple -> to use it within my update statement. But the trailing comma is preventing me from executing the query. What should I change here to make it work? Thanks in advance.

**Note: the list can have an N number of elements**

```
 transaction_ids_list = ['5b678ujhgfr']
```

The logs are showing me the tuple looks like the following:

```
   Original tuple : ('5b678ujhgfr',)
   # the comma at the end of the tuple is preventing me from executing update_query
```

Error from log

```
  Exception Occurred -- syntax error at or near ")" LINE 5: ...TRANSACTION_ID IN ('5b678ujhgfr',);
```

Code below

```
    # Connect to the PostgreSQL database
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
    print("Connection successfull, for update")
    logging.info("Connection successful for update")
    
    # Convert the list to a tuple for use in the SQL IN clause
    transaction_ids_tuple = tuple(transaction_ids_list)
    print("Original tuple :", transaction_ids_tuple)

    # Get the current date and time
    current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    # Check if the tuple is not null or empty before executing the update query
    if transaction_ids_tuple:
        update_query = f"""
            UPDATE SCHEMA_X.TABLE124
            SET PUBLISHED = '{current_datetime}',
            EVENT_PUBLISHED = TRUE
            WHERE TRANSACTION_ID IN {transaction_ids_tuple};
        """
        
        # Create a cursor and execute the update query
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(update_query)
            
        # Commit the changes to the database
        connection.commit()
        print("Update successful")
    else:
        print("IDs tuple is null or empty. No update performed.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the trailing comma when format string with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554094/remove-the-trailing-comma-when-format-string-with-tuples)

Comment: the comma is what makes it a tuple. Without the comma, the parenthesis make it just a math expression. If you want to access the first element of the tuple, you use `tuple_var[0]`

Answer (score 0):

While what you've asked for is technically possible, it is both more complicated and [less secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) than using [query parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html). Here's a fixed-length example to demonstrate how query parametrization works:

```py
query = "UPDATE t SET published = %s WHERE transaction_id IN (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(query, (current_datetime, first_id, second_id))
```

which can be generalized to work for `n` transaction IDs:

```py
n_transaction_ids = len(transaction_ids_list)
transaction_id_formats = ("%s",) * n_transaction_ids
transaction_id_format = ", ".join(transaction_id_formats)
query = f"UPDATE t SET published = %s WHERE transaction_id IN ({transaction_id_format})"
cursor.execute(query, (current_datetime, *transaction_ids_list))
```

Obviously you could eliminate some of these intermediate variables, but I've kept them for demonstration purposes.