# Using regex to find files with a particular pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regexp-replace

I am new to regex. I have read various tutorials, still I have failed to run my simple codes.

My files are organized such as `"c1c2c4_aa_1"`, `"c1c2c3_aa_2"`, `"c1c2c8_aa_3"`, `"c1c3c4_aa_4"`, ... `"c1c2c4_bb_41"`, `"c1c8c9_cc_58"`, `"c1c3c11_aa_19"`

I want to find all those ones that includes `"aa"` (such as `"c1c2c3_aa_3"`) and convert them to `"c1c2c4_zz_3"`

So I want the last number and the first string before "_" remains fixed, but change the "aa" in the middle.

"c1", "c2", "c3" are some conditions.
Also, the last numbers are quite random, so I do not know them to define them.

I am interested in using regex.

I tried this:

```
con_list1 = ["c1", "c2", ... "c8"]
con_list2 = ["c1", "c2", ... "c11"]
con_list3 = ["c1", "c2", ... "c10"]

for con1 in con_list1:
    for con2 in con_list2:
        for con3 in con_list3:
            if(os.path.exists("./" + con1 + con2 + con3 + "_aa(.*)")):
                os.rename("./" + con1 + con2 + con3 + "_aa(.*)", "./" + con1 + con2 + con3 + "_zz(.*)")
```

I want the last number corresponding to the file that I rename remains fixed:

"c1c2c3_aa_3" -> "c1c2c3_zz_3"
"c1c2c3_aa_13" -> "c1c2c3_zz_13"

I am also interested in using regex and (.*) in the right way.

However, the above code seems not working.

I appreciate to help to implement this code.

Comment: Unrelated - but if you want a fun way to train your regex-fu: try  https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: Did any solution finally help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list like `con_list1 = ["c1c2c4_aa_1", "c1c2c3_aa_2", "c1c2c8_aa_3", "c1c3c4_aa_4"]` you may try something like:

```
import re


con_list1 = ["c1c2c4_aa_1", "c1c2c3_aa_2", "c1c2c8_aa_3", "c1c3c4_aa_4"]

regex = "_aa_"
subst = "_zz_"

for test_str in con_list1:
    result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 1)
```

but the most simple way is:

```
con_list1 = ["c1c2c4_aa_1", "c1c2c3_aa_2", "c1c2c8_aa_3", "c1c3c4_aa_4"]
for test_str in con_list1:
    test_str .replace('_aa_', '_zz_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find all names: "[a-z0-9]+_aa_[0-9]+"

```
names = re.findall(r'\"[a-z0-9]+\_aa\_[0-9]+\"', files_names_list.text, flags=re.I))
```

files_names_list is a list, where you have all your file names

Hope I understand you correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import os, re

con_list1 = ["c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8"]
con_list2 = ["c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8", "c9","c10", "c11"]
con_list3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8", "c9","c10"]
regex = re.compile(f'^((?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, con_list1))})(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, con_list2))})(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, con_list3))}))_aa_')

rootdir = "YOUR_ROOT_DIR"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if regex.search(file):
            os.rename(file, regex.sub(r'\g<1>_zz_', file))
```

**Note**: `os.walk()` searches in all subdirs recursively,  if you do not need that behavior, see [Non-recursive os.walk()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4117588/3832970).

This is not the most efficient way to create a dynamic pattern (a [regex TRIE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226462/3832970) would be better), but it shows a viable approach. The regex will look like

```
^((?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8)(?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|c9|c10|c11)(?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|c9|c10))_aa_
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/go6Qfj/1). Note that each item in your condition lists is `re.escape`d to make sure special chars do not prevent your file names from matching.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8)(?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|c9|c10|c11)(?:c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|c9|c10))` - Group 1 (`\g<1>` refers to this group value, if `_zz_` is not a placeholder for text starting with a digit, you can even use `\1` instead): a value from `con_list1`, then a value from `con_list2` and then a value from `con_list3`
- `_aa_` - an `_aa_` fixed string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files to rename exist in the current directory, would you
please try the following:

```
import os, re
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    m = re.match(r'((?:c\d{1,2}){3})_aa_(\d{1,2})$', f)
    if m:
        newname = m.group(1) + '_zz_' + m.group(2)
        os.rename(f, newname)
```

- `((?:c\d{1,2}){3})` matches three repetitions of the set of `c` + one or two digits.
- `(\d{1,2})` matches one or two digits.
- As the regexes above are enclosed by parentheses, the matched substrings
  are captured by `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` individually.