# Replacing substrings in a Pandas column with text from another column on a row-by-row basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ‘Ireland France Germany Poland’ | {‘Ireland’: ‘Dublin’, ‘Germany’: ‘Berlin’} |
| 'Ireland Iceland Singapore Portugal' | {‘Ireland’: ‘Dublin’, ‘France’: ‘Paris’’, ‘Norway’: ‘Olso’, 'Portugal': 'Lisbon'} |
| ‘Spain Italy Denmark’ | {‘Italy’: ‘Rome’, ‘Finland’: ‘Helsinki’} |

I'd like to replace some of the words in column A with replacements from column B. Not all the text will be replaced and there may well be replacement in B that don't affect A. I'd like to get a dataframe like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ‘Dublin France Berlin Poland’ | {‘Ireland’: ‘Dublin’, ‘Germany’: ‘Berlin’} |
| 'Dublin Iceland Singapore Lisbon' | {‘Ireland’: ‘Dublin’, ‘France’: ‘Paris’’, ‘Norway’: ‘Olso’, 'Portugal': 'Lisbon'} |
| ‘Spain Rome Denmark’ | {‘Italy’: ‘Rome’, ‘Finland’: ‘Helsinki’} |

I’ve tried `.replace (df['A'].replace(df['B'))` and `.str.replace` but they didn’t work - they both seem to require having the replacement text fixed. I’ve solved the problem by splitting column B off into a dict-type structure and iterating through my dataframe line by line, but this feels like a very bad solution. Ideally, I’d like something more Pandas native. This is a work problem and I have total control over the data.

Is there a way of doing this in standard Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option :

```
df["A"] = df[["A"]].T.replace(df["B"].to_dict(), regex=True).T
```

Or with pure python (*for efficiency*) :

```
from functools import reduce

df["A"] = [reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(*y),
                  [a, *b.items()]) for a,b in df.to_numpy()]
```

Output :

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dublin France Berlin Poland | {'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Germany': 'Berlin'} |
| 1 | Dublin Iceland Singapore Lisbon | {'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'France': 'Paris', 'Norway': 'Olso', 'Portugal': 'Lisbon'} |
| 2 | Spain Rome Denmark | {'Italy': 'Rome', 'Finland': 'Helsinki'} |

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Ireland France Germany Poland',
  'Ireland Iceland Singapore Portugal',
  'Spain Italy Denmark'],
 'B': [{'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Germany': 'Berlin'},
  {'Ireland': 'Dublin',
   'France': 'Paris',
   'Norway': 'Olso',
   'Portugal': 'Lisbon'},
  {'Italy': 'Rome', 'Finland': 'Helsinki'}]})
```

Perfplot (*~100k rows and ~300 A-words*) :

[image]

Comment: Can you time my solutions as well? And also with very long strings?

Comment: @mozway, I just did that and I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p8kc.png) for 130k rows and `A` having around 400 words, so I'm not sure about my timings. Can you test on your side, please ? By the way, for `regex_optimized`, I had to use `d = dict(ChainMap(*data["B"]))`.

Comment: for short strings that seems fair, I'd expect the regex to be more efficient for long strings and relatively large dictionaries (i.e. when reading the strings many times starts to increase complexity. Have you tried to duplicates the strings? e.g., `df['A'] = df['A']*1000`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex, which should be efficient for long strings:

```
import re

df['A'] = [re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, d)), lambda m: d.get(m.group()), s)
           for s,d in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

If your dictionary keys always have the same values (i.e., Ireland would always map to Dublin if present). You can further optimize the regex by compiling it.

```
import re

pat = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, d)))

df['A'] = [pat.sub(lambda m: d.get(m.group()), s)
           for s,d in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

Finally, if there are many dictionary entries you should pre-process it to [build a Trie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/16343464), that will be more efficient. There are the [`retrie`](https://github.com/ddelange/retrie) and [`teieregex`](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex) libraries.

Output:

```
                                 A                                                                                 B
0      Dublin France Berlin Poland                                        {'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Germany': 'Berlin'}
1  Dublin Iceland Singapore Lisbon  {'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'France': 'Paris', 'Norway': 'Olso', 'Portugal': 'Lisbon'}
2               Spain Rome Denmark                                          {'Italy': 'Rome', 'Finland': 'Helsinki'}
```