# Match a string with a word and a digit 1-9

Tags: regex

My regex is weak, in the case of the following string

```
"OtherId":47
"OtherId":7
"MyId":47     (Match this one)
"MyId":7
```

I want to pick up the string that has "MyId" and a number that is not 1 - 9

I thought I could just use:

[RegEx: How can I match all numbers greater than 49?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592488/regex-how-can-i-match-all-numbers-greater-than-49)

Combined using:
[Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator#)

But its not happening... you can see my failed attempt here:

https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=99753

Which is

```
\b"MyId":\b(?=.*^[0-10]\d)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex to match any digit `>= 10`:

```
^"MyId":[1-9][0-9]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F31gjP/2)

If *leading zeroes* are to be allowed as well then use:

```
^"MyId":0*[1-9][0-9]+$
```

`[1-9]` makes sure number starts with `1-9` and `[0-9]+` match 1 or more any digits after first digit.

Comment: If leading zeroes are to be allowed then use `^"MyId":0*[1-9][0-9]+$`

Comment: bit torn here, as this the best answer to the original (unedited) question but AndyG is the one i am currently using

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are looking for 2 or more digits:

```
\"MyId\"\:(\d{2,})
```

I have escaped the quotes and colon, and `{2,}` means 2 or more.

Comment: "_higher than 10_", but `10` would match too ;)

Comment: `\d{2,}` will also match `01` or `00`

Comment: my bad, my question technically had 2 questions "higher then 10" and 0-9 , AndyG is right, I will edit the question to be less ambiguous

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the sample regex which had `^[0-10]`, persuading me to look above 10.

Comment: bit torn here, as bellow is the best answer to the original (unedited) question but this is the best answer to the new question...

Comment: That is why there should be a single, clear, question :). Go with @anubhava 's answer as it is the more informative and popular. I won't lose sleep... ;)

Comment: I know, I really failed that day! lessons learnt for sure! Cheers Andy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact match to any number greater than 9
`^"MyId":[1-9][0-9]+$`