# How to match version strings against a minimum version number using a regex and no other packages?

Tags: python, regex

***Note**: This question is *not* about available libraries which parse version strings or about how to write regex pattern in general.
I have to feed a pattern into an API call so using another library is not an option for me.*

I need to match a version string like e.g. `"9.3"` or `"12.5"` against a minimum version number `"11.2"`. I.e. `"9.9"` or `"9.10"` must not match while `"11.2"`, `"11.10"` or `"20.0"` should.

In Python `re` is there a *reasonable* way to accomplish this? Using approaches like  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592488/regex-how-can-i-match-all-numbers-greater-than-49) lead to an expression [like this one](https://regex101.com/r/QRF2gl/1):

```
r"^(([2-9]\d|1[2-9])\.\d{1,}|11\.([2-9]|\d{2,}))(\.\d+)*$"
```

which is hard core to read and *zero* flexible.

In 2020 isn't there an easier or more generic way to deal with decimal numbers (not digits) in regular expressions in Python?

Maybe expression generators which take a more abstract description and generate expressions?

Comment: Instead of regex, best is to use ``parse_version from pkg_resources package``

Comment: Please refer to this posring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python

Comment: Why don't you convert it to float and then compare it?

Answer (score 0):

To match all integers and decimal numbers greater than or equal to `11`, use this regular expression:

## `^[1-9][1-9](\d+)?\.?\d*`

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `[1-9]` First digit must be in the range `1` to `9` (inclusive).
- `[1-9]` Same for second digit.
- `(\d+)?` Might be followed by more digits.
- `\.?` Might be followed by a decimal.
- `\d*` Might be followed by digits in the fractional part.

Comment: The full expression would be `r"^(([2-9]\d|1[2-9]).\d{1,}|11.([2-9]|\d{2,}))(.\d+)$"` - and this is what my question is about. I was asking whether there is an easier or even generic way to describe a pattern which can be easily described on an abstract level.

Comment: According to https://regex101.com/r/E6WcWH/1 your expression doesn't work for your test cases.  No idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: you're right - there was a `*` missing at the end of the line - I took an example which matches 11.2.3 (with an additional subversion), see https://regex101.com/r/QRF2gl/1

Comment: This doesn't match `20.0`

Comment: accoding to https://regex101.com/r/QRF2gl/4  it does..