# Filter a single number from a range from a column using datatables in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'd like to use `datatables` in R to filter values from a range based on a single number.

Here's an example dataset

```
testdata <- data.frame(minimum = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2),
                       maximum = c(6, 7, 6, 8, 9, 8, 10, 2)) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(range=paste0(minimum, "-", maximum))
```

which looks like this

```
> testdata
  minimum maximum range
1       1       6   1-6
2       2       7   2-7
3       3       6   3-6
4       2       8   2-8
5       3       9   3-9
6       1       8   1-8
7       1      10  1-10
8       2       2   2-2
```

I'd like to enter a number, say, 4 and then the rows where 4 is in range would be shown.

The following code produces

```
DT::datatable(testdata, filter = 'top', options = list(
  pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE
))
```

which outputs

[image]

Now, `range` is a string so cannot search for values within the ranges shown. Can I use either the first two columns for the last one to make a custom filter, that will show rows 1-7 since they all have 4 in the range?

Comment: Can you use: `DT[minimum <= 4 & maximum >= 4, ]`

Comment: Maybe with a regex but it's not very convenient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592488/regex-how-can-i-match-all-numbers-greater-than-49